# Xcode 4.5 character not show in console box , with scanf() in C language

Tags: c, xcode, scanf, xcode4.5

I have got this problem since updated to Xcode 4.5.

I typed `4555` in console box but it show only `4` in console box.

I tried different input parameters such as `%d`, `%f`, `%c` and `%s`, all have the same problem.

I don't get it. How to fix it?

My source code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input;
    // insert code here...

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("Please Enter Number : ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    getchar();
    printf("Input is : %d",input);
    return 0;
}
```

and console box shows:

```
>Hello, World!

>Please Enter Number : 4

>Input is : 4555
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug of Xcode 4.5. See:

- [xCode 4.5 console input - Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19701332?tstart=0#19701332?tstart=0)

> There's a discussion of this issue on Apple's paid developer forums. It's a bug in Xcode 4.5. Apple's engineers are looking into the issue, but there's no fix yet.
>
> There are two workarounds. The first workaround is to run your command-line app from the Terminal. In the Xcode project navigator select your executable from the Products folder. Right-click and choose Show in Finder. Double-click the executable in the Finder to launch it in the Terminal.
>
> The second workaround is to install Xcode 4.4. Choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools to access Apple's developer downloads site.

- [Re: standard input from console not working in Xcode 4.5](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Sep/msg00228.html)

> Yes, this is a confirmed regression from 4.4, and we're tracking it internally.  It is really unfortunate that this slipped in, but we'll get it fixed ASAP.

Comment: Recently a lot of minor bugs are found for each of the 0.1 releases for Xcode, which makes Apple publish patch versions very quickly... 4.4 (Jul 25) -> 4.4.1 (Aug 7), and 4.3 (Feb 16) -> 4.3.1 (Mar 8). I wonder when will 4.5.1 come out? :)

Comment: "In the Xcode project navigator select your executable from the Products folder. Right-click and choose Show in Finder. Double-click the executable in the Finder to launch it in the Terminal." by Mark Szymczyk // It's worked

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround. It still needs fix by Apple, or it would be very inconvenient for the developers.